# is it possible to merge my unregistered account with current one ?

Tags: support, merge-accounts, unregistered-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I have asked some questions, before I create my existing account with adding name and email. Its now showing the user as **Unregistered**. Is it possible to add these questions to my existing account ?

Is it possible to merge two accounts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add those questions to your existing account. Just flag that Unregistered question to the moderator attention , mentioning that "This question from unregistered account is actually mine, can you please merge it with my current account ( add your account link )".